# What's the Linux equivalent of OS X's Growl?

Tags: ubuntu, growl

I want to write scripts on Ubuntu that will notify the user through a tool analogous to Growl on OS X (specifically, the `growlnotify` command-line tool). What's the equivalent tool on Linux called?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ubuntu can show [notifications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD), which seem to be equivalent to Growl. It is accessible through [DBus](http://library.gnome.org/devel/notification-spec/#protocol) (for programs) and through the [`notify-send`](http://man.cx/notify-send) command (for shell scripts).

Comment: And how does it work, what's the `growlnotify` equivalent?

Comment: I think it's possible to send notifications from the command line, but I can't seem to find the exact command.

Comment: I believe the command is notify-send : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=642997

Comment: Now it's a useful answer ;-) Try editing your answer to incorporate that information.  Also the `zenity` and `knotify` mentions on the forum are probably worth looking into.

Comment: I would like to add that `notify-osd` in Ubuntu (which displays `notify-send` notifications) has a couple of -horrible- bugs (called "features", **seriously**) including being unable to set the timeout (even though the `-t` parameter is documented in `notify-send`) on bubbles and not being able to show multiple bubbles at once. For me, this renders notify-osd unusable and while there are patches available, I'm looking for an alternative. This is currently the best fit for me: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-never-miss-an-ubuntu-notification-again

Answer (score 7):

There is a Growl port for Linux. Found here: [Growl-for-linux](http://mattn.github.com/growl-for-linux/)

Comment: This is only the growl daemon, it doesn't include the growlnotify command. What is a growl *client* for linux that can send growl messages?

Comment: The linux equivalent of growlnotify is gntp-send. You can grab the [source](https://github.com/mattn/gntp-send) here and build it yourself. I have a question here that covers the [process of using this](https://superuser.com/questions/471590/how-do-i-use-gntp-send), but more or less the command reads as `gntp-send -a "App Name" -s host-ip-address -p "password" "title" "test"` where the host ip address is the ip address for the system you want to send the notifications to.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using KDE, it is real easy! just use the **kdialog** command that is built-in to **KDE**, as in the example below:

```
kdialog --passivepopup "Example text"
```

if you happen to be using **plain ubuntu**, then you need to install the **libnotify-bin** package by issuing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

and then you can send messages with like this:

```
notify-send "Example text"
```

the **kdialog** is a bit more interesting because it does way more than just send notifications from the command-line. you can actually build an interactive gui for your bash programs with it!

anyway, i hope this helps.