# How do I use gntp-send?

Tags: windows, growl

I'm currently attempting to hack together a way to send notifications to my Android cellphone using growl, and its various forms from Windows and Linux systems. At the current point of time, I'm using the growlnotify binary from growl for windows for testing. It works perfectly from a local system running windows, without any arguments other than the message.

However I'd like to also have notification capabilities from my linux boxen, and gntp-send seems to be a suitable tool.

Unfortunately I can't find a user guide or a man page - the closest thing is the error message, which is about all i seem to be able to get this application to do

```
gntp-send: [-u] [-i] [-a APPNAME] [-n NOTIFY] [-s SERVER:PORT] [-p PASSWORD] title message [icon] [url]
```

I've attempted using just the -s and -p arguements (which throws me the above error message), those and the -u arguement (which also throws me the above error message). I'm assuming the standard port for growl (23053) and using the correct IP address

```
gntp-send -i -a foo -n bar -s 192.168.1.140:23053 -p password test
```

sits there doing nothing.

So, how do I send a message to a system running growl for Windows, from a Linux system? I'd prefer this solution but any workable alternative would be fine. My end goal is to send a message from a linux system running a CLI install of ubuntu (version isn't important here) to a windows system running growl for windows)?

EDIT:

```
gntp-send  -s=192.168.1.140:23053 -p=password test http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1111219/IMG_0482.JPG
```

throws me a different error message `gethostbyname: Connection timed out` I'm guessing I got the arguements right but something else wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can send messages by just doing,

```
gntp-send -a "App Name" -s ip-address "title" "msg" /path/to/ico.png
```

I stumbled upon this, as i was trying too figure a way to set priorities within the sent notification. Unfortunately there are no documents for this and even the git location `/ readme` just explains how to compile but not use `:/` really frustrating

Comment: gntp-send -a "App Name" -s 192.168.1.140 -p "password" "title" "test"
did the trick - I guess encasing argugements in quotes was essential. That and my firewall was blocking it ;p. No idea why explicitly suggesting a port fails, but thats a problem for later.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is a little late but I have done up a simple man page. Can you take a look and see if it clarifies the usage?

https://raw.github.com/psinnott/gntp-send/master/gntp-send.man

**NAME** 
`gntp-send` - Utility for sending notifications to Growl using UDP or GNTP protocols

**SYNOPSIS**

```
gntp-send [-u] [-a APPNAME] [-n NOTIFY] [-s SERVER:PORT] [-p PASSWORD] title message [icon] [url]
```

**DESCRIPTION**
Sends notification to local or remote Growl application over UDP or TCP network protocols. When the notification is sent over TCP using GNTP http callbacks and both local and remote icons are supported.

**OPTIONS**

`-a` APPLICATION
        application name , defaults to gntp-send

`-n` NOTIFICATION
        notification name , defaults to gntp-send notify

`-s` HOST:PORT , -s HOST
        host and port to send notification to , host defaults to localhost and the port defaults to the protocol default (tcp: 23053 , udp: 9887) , you can specify the host only and the port defaults to the protocol default

`-p` PASSWORD
        password , defaults to not attempting authentication

`-u` send the notification over UDP , by default the notification is sent over TCP using GNTP

**POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS**

`title` mandatory , title of the notification

`message` mandatory , notification message

`icon`  optional , local file name or url of icon for the notification

`url`   optional , url to call if the notification is clicked

**DIAGNOSTICS**
Setting the environmental variable `GNTP_DEBUG` will cause the TCP traffic to be printed to `STDOUT`

`0` if the notification was delivered to Growl , this does not mean it was accepted

`-1` otherwise

Comment: Hey Peter, just a reminder that the information you're providing should have at least a summary on SU itself. If you get it wrong, you can always edit it.

Comment: I'm not sure a summary would add anything that isn't already included in the question and I thought including the full page would be a bit much. I'll add in the full page since it isn't massive.